# How do I test out changes to a python library pulled through git?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a python library that I am wanting to help out with and fix some issues. I just don't know *how to test* my changes given the complexity of how python/pip installs libraries.

I have the library installed with pip and I can run python code connecting to the library by doing an "from  import *". But now that I want to make changes to it I pulled the code with git and plan to branch to work on my changes. That's fine. I will then do a pull request to merge any changes given tests pass.

But after I make a change, *how do I integrate my changes into python to test out the changes I made with the library*? Can **pip** install my **custom/modified** version of the library?

I have looked around and haven't successfully found an answer to this but perhaps I'm not looking in the right spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can pip install my custom/modified version of the library?

Yes.

There are various ways of approaching this question.  A common solution is the use of Python [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). This allows you to create an isolated Python environment that does not share the same packages as your system Python install. You can then install things into it (such as your modified Python library) to test it out.

To get started, you need the `virtualenv` tool.  This is probably available as a package for your distribution, but you can also install it using `pip`.  Once you have it, you can run in the same directory as your code:

```
virtualenv .venv
```

This creates a virtuelenv named `.venv`.  You can call it anything you want, but naming it `.venv` (or anything starting with a `.`) means it won't clutter up the output of `ls` in your workspace.

Next, you need to activate the virtualenv:

```
. .venv/bin/activate.sh
```

This modifies your `$PATH` to place the virtualenv at the front of the list of directories. Now when you type `python` or `pip`, you'll be using the virtualenv version.

If your code has a `setup.py` file, you can install it like this:

```
pip install -e .
```

The `-e` means you want to perform an "editable" install, which means python will use the code "in place", and any changes you make will be immediately visible to the code you use for testing.

When you're done, you can run:

```
deactivate
```

This will remove the changes that `activate` made to your environment.

---

For more information:

- [Pipenv & Virtual Environments](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) discusses a higher level tool for managing virtual environments.
- [Virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is another take on a higher level management tool.

Comment: Excellent response. Very clear and succinctly related to my problem. I'll try that out now. Thank you!

Comment: I just want to also say that whenever I tried the ". .venv/bin/activate.sh" command in linux and macos, it didn't work very well. So I tried "source .venv/bin/activate" and that worked.

Comment: That's very odd.  `.` is the canonical shell command for sourcing a file. Glad you got it working, through.